# How can I reference the current directory of a script when sourcing it?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I have a script that I call via `. ./env/setenv.sh`. In this script, I'm calling a python script that's also located in `./env/`.

My current directory is along the lines of `~/dev/project/` and I'm calling *into* `~/dev/project/env` via `. ./env/setenv.sh`

My attempts (`${dirname $0}`) to reference the location of `setenv.sh` from within itself hasn't been successful, because my current working directory is considered `/bin` rather than `~/dev/project/env/` (I assume due to me sourcing it with `.`)

What other options do I have for referencing the current working directory of the `setenv.sh` script, so that it can call my `.py` script from within the same directory?

e.g.,

```
WORKING_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
echo $WORKING_DIR
export VAR=$(python $WORKING_DIR/script.py)"
```

When called via `. ./env/setenv.sh` prints: `/bin`, and can't locate `script.py`

Comment: The current working directory is the directory where relative filenames start from. It should be available in `$PWD`. But that's not what you're looking for, instead, you seem to be looking for the location of the currently executed script file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `bash`, this should work:

```
$ cat env/setenv.sh 
WORKING_DIR="$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
printf '%s is located in directory %s\n' \
         "$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"

PYT_FILE="$WORKING_DIR/script.pyt"

printf 'Python script %s is located in directory %s\n' \
         "$(basename "${PYT_FILE}")" "$(dirname "${PYT_FILE}")"

printf 'Path to Python script is %s\n' "${PYT_FILE}"

$ . ./env/setenv.sh 
setenv.sh is located in directory ./env
Python script script.pyt is located in directory ./env
Path to Python script is ./env/script.pyt
```

Comment: Thanks! This returns the current directory, but not the path to it -- how can I get it in the format that would let me do `"$(python $WORKING_DIR/script.pyt)"`?

Comment: It already is in that format.  Updated.